# How can I change my Mac OS X Services to all be in english?

Tags: snow-leopard, services, language

I am not sure how this happened, but many of my services are now in, what I believe is spanish:

[image: Screenshot of my Keyboard system prefs]

How do I change this back to English? My language in the Language & Text system pref is set to English where ever possible. I am using Mac OS X 10.6.8.

Comment: Viewed over 1000 times and not a single up vote. Le sad...

Comment: After 4 years and 3734 views, you get an upvote! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem seems to crop up occasionally, and I haven't heard a definitive solution outside of the standard troubleshooting routines: determine if the problem is a software setting by creating a new user account, rebuild permissions, and so on.

Beyond the basics, there are two solutions that might help. First, in [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2634686?threadID=2634686) over at the Apple discussion forums, someone has a similar problem and is able to resolve it by removing some spurious login items, then logging out and logging back in. It's worth looking at your login items suspiciously.

Second, you might try to change the system language to something new, like French. Log out and back in, then change back to English. It may be that you have some wonky settings left over from an old program, and that switching away from English and back re-aligns everything.

Comment: Wow. I am relieved to know other people have this problem, too. I guess I should say... ¿¡¡porque?!!

Comment: Also, I'm pretty strict on what login items I use. I've got nothing on that I don't need. I guess it's onto plan B changing to French and back again...

Comment: Bingo. Changing to french and back again did it. For all those interested, the language was changed in the Language & Text System pref. I dragged French to be the first language in the list of languages I prefer. Logged out/in again. Switched back to English. Logged out/in again. And all was well.